# Is it safe to check if a string equals to a qsTr string in a multi language app - qml

Tags: qt, qml

So what if I have a the following property:

`property string someString: qsTr("Text")`

and I have the following function:

```
function isEqual(toThisString) {
  if (someString === toThisString) {
    return true
  } else 
    return false
  }
}
```

My question is what if my application has a translation to some other language other than English. Will the function still compare to "Text" or will it compare to the translated string?

Comment: To the translated string. And doing checks on user-visible strings sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example with Qt:

```
const QString english = "Hello world");
const QString spanish = QObject::tr(english); // Hola mundo
```

Is equal?

```
qDebug() << "Is equal? " << (english == spanish); 
qDebug() << "Is equal? " << (QObject::tr(english) == spanish);
```

Result:

```
Is equal? false
Is equal? true
```

You have to translate every string, and should be the same string exactly. It's dificult to manage, looks like a recipe for disaster.

You have to use an alternative data field to compare values, avoid strings. Example for a QCombobox:

```
enum Countries {EEUU = 0, Spain, France};
QCombobox* combo = new QCombobox;
combo->addItem(QObject::tr("EEUU"), EEUU);
combo->addItem(QObject::tr("Spain"), Spain);
combo->addItem(QObject::tr("France"), France);
```

To get the selected country or compare with a field in the combo model, you could use currentData() function or something like this.